# minimising sum of distances

Tags: geometry

I have three points $A(-3.5, 0), B(2,0), C(0,3)$.

I am looking for the fourth point $D(0,d)$ such that $AD + BD + CD$ is minimal. Fermat does not work here due to $D$ lying on the y-axis.

I thought I could just minimize the sum of the squares of the distances but that's not giving the correct answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by minimal? The sum you describe is a vector sum and vectors aren't usually ordered. Do you mean that the magnitude of the resultant vector should be minimal?

Comment: He clearly means to minimize the sum of the three distances.  This is a sum of three scalars.

Comment: @MarkFischler If it's clear then why didn't the sum of squares work?

Comment: @JohnDouma: because the sum of squares is not equal to the square of the sum.

Comment: yes, I meant the sum of the 3 scalars. just not sure why sum of squares didn't work. do I have to just use the sum of the actual distances instead?

Comment: @shuck: check the hint below, and compare $(\Sigma d)^2$ with $AD^2+BD^2+CD^2$.

Comment: @shuck Just use the squares. You should get $d=1$.

Comment: I did get 1 but that's not the correct answer. the correct answer is 1.515

Comment: @shuck: check your math, the hint below leads to the answer $d = 1.515$.

Comment: The reference to graph theory is not apropriate.

Comment: I would really like to know the answer from your teacher since the problem is quite difficult.....and the answer is not $1.515$.

Answer (score 4):

As answered by Pavel, you need to consider minimizing $$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac {49}4 } + \sqrt{x^2+4} + \sqrt{(x-3)^2}$$ Computing the derivative $$f'x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{49}{4}}}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}+\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{(x-3)^2}}$$ you need to set it equal to $0$ to get an extremum.

Solving $f'(x)=0$ is not the must funny thing to do even if, using multiple squaring (too long steps to be reproduced here), we could show that the problem reduces to finding the zero's of $$3 x^8+65 x^6+294 x^4-2401$$ which reduces to a quartic $$3 y^4+65 x^3+294 x^2-2401$$ using $y=x^2$. That is to say that it is solvable using radicals (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)).  Applying the method would lead, for the smallest root, to the monster $$y=\frac{1}{12} \left(-65-\sqrt{1873-84 \sqrt[3]{7}\, 33^{2/3}}+6 \sqrt{\frac{1873}{18}+7
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{3}} \,11^{2/3}+\frac{45305}{18 \sqrt{1873-84 \sqrt[3]{7} \,
   33^{2/3}}}}\right)$$ the numerical value of which being $y\approx 2.28846675156653$ corresponding to $x\approx 1.51276791067451$.

I am almost sure that you (no one) would use it and the simplest is consider numerical methods (Newton being probaly the simplest). Considering $f'(x)$, by inspection, we get $$f'(0)=-1$$ $$f'(1)=-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{53}}\approx -0.278065$$ $$f'(2)=-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{4}{\sqrt{65}}\approx 0.203246$$ So, let us use Newton starting with $x_0=\frac 32$. We need $$f''(x)=\frac{98}{\left(4 x^2+49\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{4}{\left(x^2+4\right)^{3/2}}$$  and the iterates,  given by $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f'(x_n)}{f''(x_n)}$$ will be $$x_1=1.51272479056563$$ $$x_2=1.51276791018085$$ $$x_3=1.51276791067451$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.

For this value of $x$, $f(x)\approx 7.80785$.

**Edit**

Knowing, at least by inspection, that the solution is close to $\frac 32$,we could have made the problem simpler expanding $f(x)$ as a Taylor series around this value. This would give $$f(x)=\left(4+\sqrt{\frac{29}{2}}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{58}}-\frac{2}{5}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{16}{125}+\frac{49}{58 \sqrt{58}}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the high order terms (that is to say, just focusing on the quadratic), the derivative cancels at $$x=\frac{329672-3375 \sqrt{58}}{2 \left(53824+6125 \sqrt{58}\right)}\approx 1.51272$$ (this corresponds to the first iterate of Newton method) and for this value $$f(x)=\frac{55008919 \sqrt{58}-30634088}{49732188}\approx 7.80785$$

Comment: A beautiful answer!!

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud. Thank you ! It is a difficult problem, by the end.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Sigma d = AD + BD + CD$.

Hint:

$\Sigma d = \sqrt{3.5^2 + x^2} + \sqrt{2^2 + x^2} + \sqrt{(x-3)^2}$.

Now you can find the minimum of $\Sigma d$ as a function of x.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. that what I did. I just then thought that I could instead maximise the sum of the sqares. I know that sum of squares is not equal to square of the sum but thought x would be the same.